Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания и большие буквы?

Надо ли начальные слова в кавычках писать с большой буквы? Нужно ли двоеточие?

Знает Оля и о летних приметах: "если июль жаркий, то декабрь будет морозный", "комары летают роем - будет хорошая погода".
Следуя девизу компании: "Наша цель - прогресс", сотрудники рассматривают только современные технологии.

Всё ли нормально тут? Нужна ли точка в конце?

Когда в моменты отчаяния он спрашивал: "Что ж ты делаешь? Это же самоубийство", она отвечала: "Всё не так!".

✦ О приметах
Я думаю, что лучше это предложение написать так (с двоеточием, с большими буквами и с тире вместо дефиса):
Знает Оля и летние приметы: "Если июль жаркий, то декабрь будет морозный", "Комары летают роем — будет хорошая погода".

Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова предложение, выражение, надпись и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие... [§ 51, примечание]

✦ О девизе
Пишем без двоеточия, в девизе используем прописную букву и тире:
Следуя девизу компании "Наша цель — прогресс", сотрудники рассматривают только современные технологии.

Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится: <...>
Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана...  [§ 51, примечание]

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
Такой он, этот маршрут, что никого не оставит в стороне, каждому даст оценку по делам и поступкам, проверит на верность девизу «Берем с коммунистов пример!» (Моя Родина ― СССР // «Юный натуралист», 1975);
Куда выгодней было следовать девизу «Победителей не судят!», сводить историю войны к воспеванию великого подвига... (Георгий Арбатов. Человек Системы).
✦ О предложении с двумя репликами
Здесь точка после кавычек не нужна:
Когда в моменты отчаяния он спрашивал: "Что ж ты делаешь? Это же самоубийство", она отвечала: "Всё не так!"

Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, а также многоточие ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками, а точка — после них. <...> Лёжа на тюке и плача, он дёргал руками и ногами и шептал: «Мама! Мама!» [§ 48]

В вашем предложении смущает то, что при наличии глагола "спрашивал" прямая речь не заканчивается вопросительным знаком. Может, лучше использовать говорил, возмущался или удивлялся.
• Вот предложение, в котором отражены особенности оформления прямой речи:
Она закричала: «Куда?» — и он ответил: «Да за белилами!» (Н. Л. Трауберг. Сама жизнь).
Знаки препинания при прямой речи
